# Setting the click area of a custom UIView

Tags: ios, uikit

Is it possible to increase the clickable area of a `UIView` subclass?

I would rather do it without subclassing it's superview. Is that possible?

I've seen how to do it by overriding `hitTest:withevent:` and `pointInside:withEvent:` on the superview, but as I said, I would rather avoid that.

Comment: please some some code and screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a container view that has a larger area, with a transparent background, that contains a subview that has your visible part?  This is a quick and easy way to increase the tap area of a button, for instance.